# PDO, output all data from a table

Tags: php

I have been trying to output data from a db table but I can't seem to do it, it doesn't show up no matter what I do. I tried using foreach but no dice. This code was taken from a phpacademy tutorial and I am trying to modify it by adding a bit of functionality like being able to gather all data from the database using pdo

```
$bgItems = DB::getInstance()->getAll('background_image');

echo '<pre>', var_dump($bgItems), '</pre>';

foreach($bgItems as $bgItem) {
    echo $bgItem;
}
```

This is what the DB class looks like with the method i'm trying to implement:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }

            if($this->_query->execute()) {
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
        if(count($where) === 3) { 
            $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

            $field      = $where[0];
            $operator   = $where[1];
            $value      = $where[2];

            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }

        else {
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table}";
            if(!$this->query($sql)->error()) {
                return $this;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getAll($table) {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table);
    }
```

And this is the output I get when trying to view the data retrieved using var_dump, which obviously looks like a complicated array.

```
object(DB)#3 (5) {
  ["_pdo":"DB":private]=>
  object(PDO)#4 (0) {
  }
  ["_query":"DB":private]=>
  object(PDOStatement)#8 (1) {
    ["queryString"]=>
    string(30) "SELECT * FROM background_image"
  }
  ["_error":"DB":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_results":"DB":private]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#7 (2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["name"]=>
      string(28) "4ee269991861331957002e21.jpg"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#9 (2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["name"]=>
      string(36) "22769-interesting-cat-meme-rv31.jpeg"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#10 (2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["name"]=>
      string(50) "10645322_300758350130075_5393354656605964412_n.jpg"
    }
  }
  ["_count":"DB":private]=>
  int(3)
```

}

**UPDATED**

This is the result when directly return the results taken from the protected _results variable from the DB class

```
    array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#7 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(28) "4ee269991861331957002e21.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#9 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(36) "22769-interesting-cat-meme-rv31.jpeg"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#10 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["name"]=>
    string(50) "10645322_300758350130075_5393354656605964412_n.jpg"
  }
}
```

Comment: I will suggest you to use `notORM` library, it works on PDO and very good api

Answer (score 0):

You need to return results not a class itself, well you could use a class but you need to implement iterator.

```
public function getAll($table) {
        if( $this->action('SELECT *', $table) ) return $this->_results;
        return false;

}
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but it is still returning an array with stdClass. Could you please tell me how to iterate on this to make it appear? I included the output at the end of the main post. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just converted the object into an array in order to manipulate it using this

```
class Convert {
    public function objectToArray($d) 
    {
        if (is_object($d)) {
            // Gets the properties of the given object
            // with get_object_vars function
            $d = get_object_vars($d);
        }

        if (is_array($d)) {
            /*
            * Return array converted to object
            * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
            * for recursive call
            */
            return array_map([__CLASS__, __METHOD__], $d);
        } else {
            // Return array
            return $d;
        }
    }
}
```